# Add multiple choice option to quiz generator

Tags: javascript, html

I have a multiplication quiz that keeps score and tracks how long the user takes to complete the quiz.

I want to add my question generator to this code.

The generator should pull information from arrays and random numbers to create questions like this example:

```
Question:
Cinnamon has 2 pizza. 
Sammy has 6 more. 
What is the total amount they have altogether? 

Answer:
10
```

The question takes the names from a random name array and the numbers from random numbers.

I am able to calculate the answer but I want to display the answer in multiple choice options.

I want to use random numbers to add to the answer to give wrong answer options.

Example:

```
Question:
Cinnamon has 2 pizza. 
Sammy has 6 more. 
What is the total amount they have altogether?

Option list:    
A) (correct answer)10 + random number  (wrong option)
B) (correct answer)10 - random number  (wrong option) 
C) Correct answer 10
D)(correct answer)10 + random number  (wrong option)
```

The order of the options should be shuffled.

Code for question generator:

```js
var myName = ['Beth', 'Chris', 'Carl', 'April', 'Cinnamon'];
var myMoreNames = ['Sammy', 'Dan', 'Devron', 'Livron', 'Paul'];
var myamount = ['twice as many', 'half', 'three times as many'];

var myfood = ['pizza', 'steak', 'pies', 'cookies', 'brownies'];

var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * myName.length);
var rand2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * myfood.length);
var rand3 = Math.floor(Math.random() * myMoreNames.length);
var rand4 = Math.floor(Math.random() * myamount.length);

var concat = myName[rand];
var concat2 = myfood[rand2];
var concat3 = myMoreNames[rand3];
var concat4 = myamount[rand4];

num1 = parseInt(Math.random() * 20) + 1;
num2 = parseInt(Math.random() * 20) + 1;

theSum = parseInt(num1) + parseInt(num2) + parseInt(num1);

var randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 4;;
var randomnumber2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20) + 10;

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = (concat) + " has " + num1 + "  " + (concat2) + ".  " + (concat3) + "  " + "  " + " has " + num2 + "  " + " more. What is the total amount they have altogether? " + theSum;
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: http://promise2code.com/quiz99.html                                                       var myName = ['Beth', 'Chris', 'Carl', 'April', 'Cinnamon'];    
var myMoreNames = ['Sammy', 'Dan', 'Devron', 'Livron', 'Paul'];    
var myamount = ['twice as many', 'half', 'three times as many'];    

var myfood = ['pizza', 'steak', 'pies', 'cookies', 'brownies'];    
var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * myName.length);
var rand2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * myfood.length);
var rand3 = Math.floor(Math.random() * myMoreNames.length);
var rand4 = Math.floor(Math.random() * myamount.length);

Comment: i am new so i need little help with how to add the code on here

Comment: What is your question? Imagine one of your students dumped that load of facts and desires on your desk, how would you react? You'd ask the student to extract a specific question out of the mess and ask that. You need to do just that.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick. It's a lot of code, and the basic skeleton of what it would look like. You'll have to change the specificities and details to make it fit into what you want to do. If you have any questions on what anything is doing or how to modify it to fit into your code, let me know!

The main function to note is the `randomAnswerGenerator`. It accepts the correct answer value as a parameter and will return an object containing an array of the randomly generated answer choices, and the index of the correct answer.

I tried to comment what was going on and what you would likely change. Hope this helped.

```js
function randomAnswerGenerator(answer){
    var answerChoices = [];
    var correctAnswerIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
  
    var checkUnique = function(val){ //Let's put function here for readability
        for(var i = 0; i < answerChoices.length; i ++){
            if(answerChoices[i] == val){
              return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
    
      for(var i = 0; i < 4; i ++){
        if(i == correctAnswerIndex){ //If this is the index for the correct answer, put correct answer here
          answerChoices.push(answer);  
        }
        else{
          var newAnswer = -1;
          do{ 
            var randOpt = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2); //Should we add or subtract the random number
            var randBase = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) + 1; //Plus 1 so it doesn't equal zero. Change the 5 to modify how much the generated answers will differ from the real answer
                if(randOpt == 0){ //Add
                  newAnswer = answer + randBase;
                }
                else{ //Subtract
                  newAnswer = answer - randBase;
                }
          } while(!checkUnique(newAnswer)) //Make sure wrong answer doesn't conflict with any other answers
            answerChoices.push(newAnswer); //Add new fake answer to list
        }
      }
    var returnData = {
      answerChoices: answerChoices,
      correctIndex: correctAnswerIndex
    }
    return returnData;
  }
  
  function generateList(){
     var parent = document.getElementById("main");
        while (parent.firstChild) { //Just clearing the list everytime a new one is generated
          parent.removeChild(parent.firstChild);
        }    
    
     var data = randomAnswerGenerator(10);
     var answerChoices = data.answerChoices;
     var correctIndex = data.correctIndex;
           for(var i = 0; i < answerChoices.length; i ++){
               var div = document.createElement('div');  
               div.innerHTML = answerChoices[i];
               if(i == correctIndex){
                   div.setAttribute('class','correctChoice') //Do whatever you want here to identify the correct answer  
               }
               parent.appendChild(div);
           }
  }
```

```html
<div onclick='generateList()'> Click to generate answer </div>
<div id="main"></div>
```

Comment: i can read and get the code but i am not sure where to put it with my code or where i add the radio buttons to go with it.    Are you able to combine both your code and my code for me and add the radio button       http://image.prntscr.com/image/f5af52fbc3c64ae58f315c4675edea77.png is what im hoping for

Comment: i am not able to get this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41142480/add-multiple-choice-option-to-quiz-generator. The last option doesnt display the question. The second to last response is what i want but i am not able to keep a score with it or get it to display as you did. But this

Answer (score 0):

Solution integrated into your code. I'm posting as a separate answer because the other answer is far more important, as it contains the logic and explanation towards your question.

```js
var myName = ['Beth', 'Chris', 'Carl', 'April', 'Cinnamon'];
var myMoreNames = ['Sammy', 'Dan', 'Devron', 'Livron', 'Paul'];
var myamount = ['twice as many', 'half', 'three times as many'];

var myfood = ['pizza', 'steak', 'pies', 'cookies', 'brownies'];

var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * myName.length);
var rand2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * myfood.length);
var rand3 = Math.floor(Math.random() * myMoreNames.length);
var rand4 = Math.floor(Math.random() * myamount.length);


var concat = myName[rand];
var concat2 = myfood[rand2];
var concat3 = myMoreNames[rand3];
var concat4 = myamount[rand4];


num1 = parseInt(Math.random() * 20) + 1;
num2 = parseInt(Math.random() * 20) + 1;


theSum = parseInt(num1) + parseInt(num2) + parseInt(num1);


function randomAnswerGenerator(answer){
    var answerChoices = [];
    var correctAnswerIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
  
    var checkUnique = function(val){ //Let's put function here for readability
        for(var i = 0; i < answerChoices.length; i ++){
            if(answerChoices[i] == val){
              return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
    
      for(var i = 0; i < 4; i ++){
        if(i == correctAnswerIndex){ //If this is the index for the correct answer, put correct answer here
          answerChoices.push(answer);  
        }
        else{
          var newAnswer = -1;
          do{ 
            var randOpt = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2); //Should we add or subtract the random number
            var randBase = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) + 1; //Plus 1 so it doesn't equal zero. Change the 5 to modify how much the generated answers will differ from the real answer
                if(randOpt == 0){ //Add
                  newAnswer = answer + randBase;
                }
                else{ //Subtract
                  newAnswer = answer - randBase;
                }
          } while(!checkUnique(newAnswer)) //Make sure wrong answer doesn't conflict with any other answers
            answerChoices.push(newAnswer); //Add new fake answer to list
        }
      }
    var returnData = {
      answerChoices: answerChoices,
      correctIndex: correctAnswerIndex
    }
    return returnData;
  }


document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = (concat) + " has " + num1 + "  " + (concat2) + ".  " + (concat3) + "  " + "  " + " has " + num2 + "  " + " more. What is the total amount they have altogether? ";


var randAnswers = randomAnswerGenerator(theSum);

for(var i = 0; i < randAnswers.answerChoices.length; i ++){ //Can definitely clean this up. Fine for now, but not best way
  document.getElementById("demo").appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
  var but = document.createElement('input');
  var label = document.createElement('label');
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  but.setAttribute('type','checkbox');
  label.textContent = randAnswers.answerChoices[i];
  div.appendChild(but);
  div.appendChild(label);
  document.getElementById("demo").appendChild(div);
}
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
```